# Add a custom font (Ubuntu) on WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

How can I import an non-standard font (for example from [Ubuntu](http://font.ubuntu.com/)) into a C# project for use in winforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find your font and download it (For ex, http://font.ubuntu.com/ or  http://www.dafont.com/), then you can use it easily in .Net.

A sample WinForms application:

```
Font CreateFont(string fontFile,float size,FontStyle style)
{
    using (var pfc = new PrivateFontCollection())
    {
        pfc.AddFontFile(fontFile);
        using (var fontFamily = new FontFamily(pfc.Families[0].Name, pfc))
        {
            return new Font(fontFamily, size, style);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
someControl.Font = CreateFont("UbuntuMono-R.ttf", 20, FontStyle.Regular);
```